# Remove duplicate unsorted objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[1, {a: 'b', c: 'd'}, {c: 'd', a: 'b'}, {e: 'f'}, 'b']
```

What I want to do is that I want to remove the duplicates from this array whether they are objects or not so that the final array could become this:

```
[1, {a: 'b', c: 'd'}, {e: 'f'}, 'b']
```

I have seen many solutions on the site but none works for my issue. How could I do it?

I tried this:

```
function uniq_fast(a) {
    var seen = {};
    var out = [];
    var len = a.length;
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var item = a[i];
         if(seen[item] !== 1) {
               seen[item] = 1;
               out[j++] = item;
         }
    }
    return out;
}
```

But this removed the third object aswell.

Thanks.

Comment: What solutions did not work?

Comment: All the .filter and .unique (by extending Array) approaches.

Comment: What did you try? Please show the code you've tried instead of just asking for a solution.

Comment: @wmock I was really in a hurry. :P Sorry for that. But I have edited the question.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui for each element you need to check the type of element something like:

For Array:
`Array.isArray([1,2])`

For Objects:
`if (typeof obj == "object")`

Then if it is an array or object you have write function to compare the array with other arrays and objects with other objects....

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare references and not the object's contents, you can use:

```
arr.reduce(function(accumulator, element){
   if (accumulator.indexOf(element) !== -1) return accumulator;
   return accumulator.concat(element);
}, []);
```

Otherwise, you need to create a function that compares the object's contents, for example:

```
function objectsMatch(obj1, obj2) {
  if (obj1 === obj2) return true;
  for (var prop in obj1) {
    if (!(prop in obj2) || obj1[prop] !== obj2[prop]) return false; 
  }
  for (var prop in obj2) {
    if (!(prop in obj1)) return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then use something like:

```
arr.reduce(function(accumulator, element){
   if (accumulator.some(function(otherElement){
          return objectsMatch(element, otherElement);
       })) return accumulator;
   return accumulator.concat(element);
}, []);
```

Comment: And I want to compare the object's content.s

Comment: Check out my edited solution. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Will this work only for the above sample provided array?

Comment: It should work for *most* arrays of objects. It won't work for objects with non-enumerable properties.

Comment: Note that this is only compatible with Internet Explorer 9 and above. For 8 and below, you need to polyfill `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.some`.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do it for you. It uses `Object.keys()` to cross reference the objects. If seen is populated with a known key and the known key content doubles that of the object in seen, delete property from object. Finally if object is empty delete the whole object from the array using splice. Note this solution only works if all input is like the provided sample. Else the function needs to be written recursively.

```
var abc = [1, {a: 'b', c: 'd'}, {c: 'd', a: 'b'}, {e: 'f'}, 'b'];

function uniq_fast(a) {
    var seen = {};
    var deleteObject = [];
    var len = a.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         if (Object.prototype.toString.call(a[i]) === '[object Array]' || Object.prototype.toString.call(a[i]) === '[object Object]')
         {
            var test = Object.keys(a[i]);
            var len2 = test.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < len2; ++j)
            {
                if (seen[test[j]] && a[i][test[j]] === seen[test[j]])
                {
                    delete a[i][test[j]];
                }
                else
                {
                    seen[test[j]] = a[i][test[j]];
                }
            }
            if (Object.keys(a[i]).length == 0)
            {
                deleteObject.push(i);
            }
        }

    }
    for (var i = 0; i < deleteObject.length; ++i)
    {
        a.splice(deleteObject[i], 1);
    }

    return a;
}

console.log(uniq_fast(abc));
```